# Layout bug on desktop web: spacing and alignment of the Next Privilege popup's Learn More button

Tags: bug, web

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log in.
2. Go to your profile for any SE site (not your network profile)
3. Click on the "next privilege" progress bar.

What's wrong:

1. The text showing your numeric progress is right up against the Learn More button, with no space between.
2. There is also no space above the button.

[image: screenshot showing problem]

I *think* that, in the past, the Learn More button was right-aligned in the popup. I tried `float: right; margin-top: 0.3em;` in my web inspector, and that seemed to fix the issue:

[image: screenshot showing solution]

I'm obviously not suggesting that SE folks just copypasta my solution and ship it. Just trying to do as much of the work as I can.

I tried on Meta and SO; I see it in both places, so I don't think it's site-specific nor dependent on which badge you're tracking. Chrome 84 and Safari 13.1.2 both show the issue. I don't imagine this part is relevant, but in the interest of thoroughness, I'm using a 2018 15" Macbook Pro running Catalina 10.15.6.

EDIT: I agree that this is a duplicate of the linked question, but mine and the linked questions are, IMO, *not* duplicates of the one *that* one is linked to. Related, but not duplicates. Close mine, but reopen that one?

Comment: Agree about dupe not being dupe by itself, but it was closed by SE staff, so prefer not to reopen single handedly. I did post a comment to the one who closed it, hopefully she'll see and reconsider.